# Totaling a Summary Line in Data Table

Tags: sum, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I hve a `sumField` method which totals values in a given column:

```
sumField (key) {
    let total = 0
    const sum = this.tableName.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        return (total += +cur[key])
    }, 0)
    return sum
}
```

Inside my data table I call `sumField` to produce a rolling total of the values in a specific column of my data table:

```
<template v-slot:[`body.append`]="{headers}">
    <tr class="summary">
        <td v-for="(header,i) in headers" :key="i">
          <div v-if="header.value == 'COL HEADER 1'">
          {{ sumField('COL HEADER 1') }}</div>
          <div v-else-if="header.value == 'COL HEADER 2'">
          {{ sumField('COL HEADER 2') }}</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

This is presented on screen as an additional line of the data table, and the values change depending on the filters applied to the table.

Is there a way to sum the values calculated, and show this as a rolling total value also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution which I hope might provide some help to others in the future!

Started by creating a new function:

```
sumTot (col1, col2) {
    var one = col1
    var two = col2
    var tot = col1 + col2
    return tot
}
```

Then I called `sumTot` giving the arguments of the individual `sumField` calls:

```
{{ sumTotal(sumField ('COL HEADER 1'), sumField ('COL HEADER 2')) }}
```

That gives me a dynamically updated running total value.